# Our files are not updated in CrossRider debug mode

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser-extension, crossrider

We are using CrossRider to develop an extension for Internet Explorer. I tested our extension in debug mode, I changed the base URL of the Local File Paths - but the files are not updated after saving the new base URL - I see alerts from the previous version and I already removed these alerts in the new version. How do I update the base URL and do I have to uninstall the extension and reinstall it every time I want to change the base URL? I tried to uninstall the extension and reinstall it and it doesn't solve the problem, I still get the code from CrossRider's website and not the code of my base URL.

By the way, our base URL is in HTTP and the websites are in HTTPS, does it matter?

Our Extension ID is 43889. I'm using Internet Explorer 11 but this extension should work on all versions of Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [POST/GET requests to localhost not working on a html page resource on IE](https://getsatisfaction.com/crossrider/topics/post-get-requests-to-localhost-not-working-on-a-html-page-resource-on-ie?utm_source=notification&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=new_reply&utm_content=reply_button&reply[id]=15163132#reply_15163132) thread on the Crossrider forum that relates to the same issue:

> As of IE11, EPM(Enhanced Protected Mode) is enabled by default. This
>   is a problem for loopback connections because when IE11 is in EPM mode
>   it runs in an isolated AppContainer and AppContainers are not allowed
>   to send network traffic to the local computer, so It's not possible to
>   make requests to localhost unless the html page I'm making a request
>   from is stored locally on my computer.
>
> Workaround: There's a free web debugging application called fiddler,
>   which has a tool that allows AppContainers to send network traffic to
>   the local computer. If there's anyone with the same problem as me I
>   would recomend downloading and installing Fiddler and following this
>   tutorial. After using the tool to allow IE's AppContainer to send
>   traffic to the local computer, like it shows on the tutorial, the
>   requests to localhost on IE11 are now working with no problems! :)

[**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]